# black gmail in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

When I click whatever in fresh loaded gmail, it will does black. What it couses? How can I repair it?

- OS: **Windows 7 64bit**
- Browser: **Google Chrome 29.0**

[image: black gmail]

Comment: According to [this Google Groups discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/RRo9xsCxM74/discussion[1-25-false]), updating to the latest version of Chrome fixes this error for many people. Are you running the most recent version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache and history. If that doesn't work, open an incognito session (ctr+shift+n) and see if it works from there.

Comment: …and if not, then try disabling extensions, then plugins, and finally test it with a new, empty [User Data Directry](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). If it works then, it means it’s a problem with your user profile.